# How do you kill a Terminal Services session remotely of you don't have Active Directory in your network?

Tags: terminal-server, windows

Any ideas on how to do this or if it is possible at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you can access the machine via SMB/RPC, then you should be able to install the administrative tools on your client machine.  Then fire up the Remote Desktop (Terminal Services) manager.  Point the console at the remote machine, and select the session to disconnect.

[image: RDS Remote computer]

Comment: The only other way than using the mmc tools (via RPC) would be to setup some sort of program to listen for connections and run commands locally on the TS server.  From there, you can run wmi scripts or even use the built-in command-line tools.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775998(WS.10).aspx for more info on the command line stuff.

Comment: In a non-domain environment, this usually produces 'access denied'.

Comment: It work fine in non-domain envirinments.  Just pre-authenticate to the server as an admin before starting the mmc.

Answer (score 1):

I typically will RDP to the server using the console session, then logout people who are connected there. Take a look at mstsc's /console switch.

SOME RDP clients however, will try the console session automatically, hopefully that's not the case for you. Past that, you can look at the other answers posted to run a remote command to force a logoff.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answert to your question. But when I have session that is not responding, I usally login as administrator using `mstsc /admin`  and then use `Terminal Services Manager` to kill my inactive session in Windows Server.